# How to Add CC or Bcc in Send Email With SendGrid in .NET Core 3.1 and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

How do I send an email With CC And BCC?
I am using .NET Core 3.1 and wrote this `Send` method:

```cs
public async Task<Response> Send(string ToUser, string Subject, string TextContent, string HtmlContent, string base64context = null, string filename = "")
{
    string apiKey = AppConfiguration.SendGridApiKey;
    SendGridClient client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
    EmailAddress from = new EmailAddress(AppConfiguration.SendGridFromEmail, AppConfiguration.SendGridFromName);
    EmailAddress toMail = new EmailAddress(ToUser);
    SendGridMessage msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, toMail, Subject, TextContent, HtmlContent);
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(base64context) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filename))
    {
        msg.AddAttachment(filename, base64context);
    }

    return await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
}
```

Comment: For future questions, please include your code as a code snippet instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [SendGrid's documentation](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send) and [source code](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/main/tests/SendGrid.Tests/Integration.cs#L79), here's how:

```cs
SendGridMessage msg = new SendGridMessage();
msg.AddCc(new EmailAddress("test1@example.com", "Example User1"));          
msg.AddBcc(new EmailAddress("test2@example.com", "Example User2"));
```

Comment: Yes, it's Work in My Case.
Thank you